# WCF "Method Not Allowed" in Visual Studio integrated webserver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I have two web projects in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, One hosting a WCF service and another that I am using to consume the WCF service. The service in question exposes a webHttpBinding endpoint and take JSON as input and returns JSON.

I have used Jquery ajax to consume the service from the client web app like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = '{"myobject":{"Business":"PIZZA"}}';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://localhost:1212/JobInfo.svc/ReturnThisString",
        error:
            function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");
            },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("BoolValue: " + data.GetDataUsingDataContractResult.BoolValue);
            alert("StringValue: " + data.GetDataUsingDataContractResult.StringValue);
        }
    });

});
```

And I get the following error in the Firebug HTML request:

```
http://localhost:1212/JobInfo.svc/ReturnThisString 405 Method Not Allowed
```

But if run the exact same file in the web project that is hosting the project it works fine.

The hosting project is running on set port localhost:1212 and the client on localhost:RANDOM_PORT. As the localhost is the same I would imagine its not a Cross Domain issue? Or does the port part count also?

The server contract is as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate="ReturnThisString", 
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
EventListArgs ReturnThisString(EventListArgs myobject);

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class EventListArgs {

    [DataMember( IsRequired = false)]
    public string Business;

    [DataMember( IsRequired = false)]
    public string Feeder;

}
```

And the implemented code is:

```
public EventListArgs ReturnThisString(EventListArgs myobject)
{
    return myobject;
}
```

This was added as a simple method to prove I had not just done something silly. What I like to call a sanity check. Its a simple function that takes a complex(of type other then string) JSON object as a parameter and returns a complex JSON object.

[image]

As you can see above I have two web project that use the Visual Studio Built in web server (local IIS install not possible). The above configuration does not work but if you can see I have also got the Darkside test page in the server host which is an exact copy from the client and this work with no problems at all.

Comment: Okay but im not sure why it works then if I run it from built-in Cassini in the same web:-( So when I run it on the same web that is hosting the SVC file it works fine.

Comment: Does your service actually expect an http POST or GET? Have you tried that url from a browser with an html <form> tag and do a POST that way rather than from JavaScript? The Method Not Allowed is being issued by your WCF Service application. No this is not a cross domain issue.

Comment: Where do you run the service from? Casini server, IIS or something else? Also, what happens when you send a request using a tool like fiddler? Also make sure your actually dealing with a POST method and that the mimetype is correct

Comment: `[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate="ReturnThisString", 
                BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
                RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        EventListArgs ReturnThisString(EventListArgs myobject);`


The above is the Contract, can't try on URL as its a POST. Also the same code works on the web project that is hosting the WCF service:-(

Both the server and client are running in Casini. Both as web projects.

Comment: That is really strange, for starters it shoudn't matter which project you have the JS in since its all clientside and will most likely be executed by the browser anyways (which ofourse has no clue about the VS projects). Again i would suggest using a tool like fidder to capture the working and non-working requests and try and find if there are any differences

Comment: Switch on WCF tracing by adding the following to your web.config.  It's pretty verbose, so the answer could well leap out at you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Updating your question to include your server side code, interface and bindings will also help.

Comment: Updated code, also I have installed this on an IIS as two separate IIS websites and works as expected. I did need to change the URL to point from localhost:1212 to new server name but that is only change I have made to code. I would guess that the build in Web Server in Visual Studio just doesn’t support this? This will be rather annoying as I will have to host both my client and host in same app for development as it is not possible to have ISS access even on local machine at the company I am working for.

Comment: Yes, do NOT use the Visual Studio integrated webserver for WCF, you'll run into TONS of issues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/)
It's got the same features as a full blown IIS and requires no install.
A simple command line is all you need to start it up.  It should get rid of the Casini related errors you were getting.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will download and try out.

Comment: Im afraid IIS express supports .net 4.0 only. As my company has not upraded its SOE to have .net 4.0 this option is not available to me. I am currently getting around this issue by coping site to webserver.

Comment: iisexpress /?  my friend.
if you launch it as iisexpress /clr:3.5 you will be running under 3.5 framework.

I seem to be incapable of using this mini-markdown syntax...

Comment: Yes, but it still requires .net framework 4.0 to be installed to run;-( Im afraid where I work this is not possible.